# Rest Call to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, rest

I am trying to login to Azure with my c# code and was able to find something like this on the net.

Not sure what to pass in the scope array here and once I get the access token, how can I make the rest call ?

```
public static string getAccessToken(string[] scopes)
{
   var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();
   return interactiveCredential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes, null)).Token;
}
```

Comment: you want to access your subscription on azure using c#?

Comment: I already have the subscription. So, I want to go to my Azure DevOps Pipeline and run the pipeline from c# code. But before going there, I need to authenticate before going to azure and need to get the token. So, how can I get there ?

Answer (score 1):

First create a Azure AD Application:

[Follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

Then get the Tenant ID , Client ID , Client Secret from the AD Application and use this class to query your azure subscription recourses.

```
class CustomLoginCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
{
    //Variables
    private static string tenantId = "<Tenant ID goes here>";
    private static string clientId = "<Client ID goes here>";
    private static string clientSecret = "<Client Secret goes here>";
    private static string windowsURL = "https://login.windows.net/";
    private static string azureManagementURL = "https://management.azure.com/";


    private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

    public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
    {
        var authenticationContext =
            new AuthenticationContext(windowsURL + tenantId);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(azureManagementURL,
            clientCredential: credential).Result;

        AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
    }
    public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);
        await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
private async void GetAzureResourcesConsumption()
        {
            var credentials = new CustomLoginCredentials();
            ConsumptionManagementClient client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(credentials);
            client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            var resources = await client.UsageDetails.ListAsync(null, null, null, top: NumberOfItems);
            var results = resources.ToList<UsageDetail>();
        }
```

Do you mean to get access token?

```
private static string GetAuthorizationToken()
    {
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ServicePrincipalPassword);
        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + AzureTenantId);
        var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        return result.Result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Amjad. I already have a subscription and have tenantId, clientId and clientsecret. I also have a function for "getAccessToken" where I need to pass scopes array as I shown in the example. So, now I need to query the url that I pass(REST call to ADO pipeline url) and get the build Id as the REST response. So how to change your code here ?

Comment: sorry but i still dont understand you issue. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok, let me explain again what I want to do :
I have getAccessToken function in my code somewhere (the person who wrote it has not used it anywhere and he left and the function is same as described above)
Firstly, I want to query AzureDevOps with this Access token (I dont know how I can do that)
So, once I make a REST call to AzureDevOps (pipeline url) - I want to get the build Id in response of that REST call.

`These are the two main things. 
1. Call getAcessToken(Not sure what to pass in scope array in my eg) and Make REST CALL with accessToken.
2. Get the response of that REST Call`

Comment: Does this help in any way ? 
I already have a subscription and have tenantId, clientId and clientsecret

Comment: yes thanks for your explanation. plus check this for scope .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Comment: this might help. https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/getting-the-scopes-and-audiences-correct-when-calling-an-api-in-azure-ad-b2c-fe4fb14a10d8

Comment: Ok, I will check these links and get the access token

Comment: How to make the rest calls after getting the access token ? I thought it should be just http call isnt it ?

Comment: I want to http call the Azure Devops pipeline (I have the url)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/how-to/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops

Comment: FYI this is not the place to have a conversation. First step, @user18093810: *edit your question with specifics* - you've now left a lot of detail buried in comments here. Second step: if you really want to discuss this, move the conversation to [chat].

Comment: And lastly: Please refrain from asking additional questions in comments, under an answer.